How to properly close pywebview window from a button?
How to properly close  pywebview window from a button?
I put together this demo of a Python Code Editor using  pywebview and codemirror.
It runs fine; However, when I use a button to close the window it does not end all the processes on Linux (Ubuntu 24.04).
See Figure 1.
When I just click the X of the window to close it does work and terminate all the processes.
When I run the same code in Windows it works fine.
When the Cancel button is clicked it calls the Api.destroy() method.
See Source here
import webview

class Api:
    def __init__(self):
        self._window = None

    def set_window(self, window: webview.Window):
        self._window = window

    def destroy(self):
        if self._window:
            self._window.destroy()
        self._window = None
    
    # other code ...

In the source I resorted to calling sys.exit() but this is a poor solution as I plan on using this code in other projects and sys.exit() would also kill a running project.
Any suggestions?
Figure 1:

